# Get Key from Value from Singleton Map - Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am looking to retrieve key from the value for a SingletonMap

```
Map<String,String> map = Collections.singletonMap("key1", "value1");
```

I am looking for a easy way to get the key, based on value. Rather then way that I have done before. Which I feel is too much overhead for a singleTon Map.

```
public static List<String> getKey(String value, Map<String, String> map) 
{
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Entry<String, String> entry:map.entrySet()) 
    {
        if(value.equals(entry.getValue())) 
        {
            keys.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Any inputs or suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: A singletonMap only has a single `key -> value` mapping, so unless the value you provide is not in the map, it's simply the first (and only) element of `map.keySet()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A singleton map has exactly one entry in it, so you can just do this:

```
    Map<String,String> map = Collections.singletonMap("key1", "value1");

    String theOnlyKeyInTheMap = map.keySet().iterator().next();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why do you want this, however I do not think that is possible in any other way. You may be able to make the code readable using something like the [Guava Maps.transformEntries](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformEntries%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.collect.Maps.EntryTransformer%29) call, supplied with a proper transformer function.

Answer (score 0):

CollectionUtils.getSingleOrNull(map.keySet())

Also Singletom map has getKey() and getValue() methods available so ((SingletonMap)map).getKey() would work as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).